Is it possible to have a pdf file with multiple dates in the cover page?
I am trying to render a Quarto file as a pdf document, and I was wondering whether the date part can be composed by two dates (e.g., 5-6 November 2024). I found such possibility in Latex (here), but I could not find anything similar for Quarto. I want to know if I could do it directly from the YAML, instead of "forcing" it with Latex.
In the YAML:
date: 05/11/2024, 06/11/2024 # or any other combination, such as "and" or "&", or even in between curly brackets
date-format: "DD/MM/YYYY"

It would return "Invalid Date". The "solution" I found was to exclude the day and leave just MMMM YYYY, which is not the ideal.
